# Seemingly duplicate logins in local groups

Tags: windows, login, security-groups

I can’t figure this one out, and it’s vague enough that I can’t determine the appropriate search terms to research it. Apologies if this is frequently asked!

On many servers on our domain, when I check the membership in the Administrators group, I often see what appears to be duplicate entries—one a domain login or group, and the other the same item followed by the SID. Example:

```
OURDOMAIN\WebLogin
OURDOMAIN\WebLogin (S-1-5-21-2000478354-guid-etc-etc)
```

They don’t appear to impact performance or security, but they are confusing. What does this mean? How do they come about? Most importantly, is it safe to delete the redundant-looking one?

Comment: Question - was the account migrated from another domain?

Comment: Quite Possibly. I'd have to review, as I wasn't involved with this side of things back when that happened. If this is a possible explanation, please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the documentation for this, but within our network, I only see this on computers/accounts that have been migrated from other domains with SID history.  As long as [the migration is complete](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2011/11/23/how-to-remove-sid-history-with-powershell/), it should be safe to delete the old ones, but as the Technet blog gets into, it better be complete.

Comment: Accepting this as answer. Deleting the oddball duplicates has no impact on performance, and it is conceivable that something like this happened during a domain transition years back.